# How to center align one child of a container while in display flex?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I know I am being very dumb right now and when I'll read the solution I will do a very big facepalm to myself : "of course!".

1. I want to center align the cell number and I want the cell icon to be moved to the left. I don't want to mess around with positions because I want it to stay centered on bigger screens too. What's the quick and I'm sure, THE OBVIOUS way? I'm having a lapsus!
2. Why I can't move up or down the cell icon? I changed the height of the container but nothing happens. left and right yes, but not up or down. Why??

It looks extremely bad here so here's the page: [Here the page](https://adz.netlify.app/contatti.html)
(Inspect the website in mobile mode, I am bulding it mobile first and there's no media queries yet)

THANK YOU!

```css
.paolo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px 0;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.iconandname {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.contactname {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.numeroandiconcell {
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.cellnumber {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.iconasmartphone {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.tap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.chiamaconuntocco {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="paolo">
        <div class="iconandname">
          <img src="images/paoloicon.svg" class="paoloicon" width="300px" alt="icona ragazzo">
          <h3 class="contactname">Paolo</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="numeroandiconcell">
          <img src="images/smartphone.svg" class="iconasmartphone" width="70px" alt="icona smartphone">
          <a class="cellnumber" href="tel:+393475924197">347 592 4197</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tap">
          <img src="images/tap.svg" class="tapicon" width="40px;" alt="icona raffigurante simbolo touch">
          <p class="chiamaconuntocco">Chiama con un tocco</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, the preview indicates that the style .numeroandiconcell is too wide.  try using a value in pixels, e.g. 300px instead of 50vw. It will stay centered, but the smaller total width would bring the telephone symbol and the number closer together. Another option is to put the telephone symbol above the number, by giving them each a separate .numeroandiconcell section.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.paolo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px 0;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.iconandname {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.contactname {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.numeroandiconcell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.cellnumber {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.iconasmartphone {
  position: relative;
}

.tap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.chiamaconuntocco {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="paolo">
        <div class="iconandname">
          <img src="https://adz.netlify.app/images/paoloicon.svg" class="paoloicon" width="300px" alt="icona ragazzo">
          <h3 class="contactname">Paolo</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="numeroandiconcell">
          <img src="https://adz.netlify.app/images/smartphone.svg" class="iconasmartphone" width="70px" alt="icona smartphone">
          <a class="cellnumber" href="tel:+393475924197">347 592 4197</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tap">
          <img src="https://adz.netlify.app/images/tap.svg" class="tapicon" width="40px;" alt="icona raffigurante simbolo touch">
          <p class="chiamaconuntocco">Chiama con un tocco</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: try this snippet

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem of the cell phone not beying Y aligned with the number. What was the problem? I saw you canceled the width of the parent container. Was this? The number though it is not center aligned, all the container it is aligned in the center. Could you tell me how to center align only the number and have the icon off-setted to the left?

Comment: removed this style   cellnumber ```margin-top: 40px;``` , iconasmartphone ```top: 5px;``` , numeroandiconcell ```width: 50vw;```

Comment: btw thanks to you. And don't forgot to accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about not wanting to change the position, because that's probably the easiest fix for what you want.

```
.numeroandiconcell {
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center
}
.iconasmartphone {
    position:absolute;
    left: 5px;
}
```

This way, the icon will stay inside the parent div (position: relative allows this), but it will sit all the way to the left, while the number is centered.

Given that you have 2 elements inside your parent div (the icon and the number itself), there's no way to truly center the number without removing the icon from the flow (like position:absolute does).